# How i could upgrade a theme from 6.2 to 7.2?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

When i run gulp upgrade from 6.2 to 7.0 i received the below error :

```
C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme>gulp upgrade
[16:54:09] Using gulpfile C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme\gulpfile.js
[16:54:09] Starting 'upgrade'...
? We recommend creating a backup of your theme files before proceeding. Are you sure you wish to start the upgrade process? Yes
[16:54:13] Starting 'upgrade:black-list'...
[16:54:13] Finished 'upgrade:black-list' after 61 ms
[16:54:13] Starting 'upgrade:replace-compass'...
[16:54:13] Finished 'upgrade:replace-compass' after 37 ms
[16:54:13] Starting 'upgrade:convert-bootstrap'...
C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme\node_modules\convert-bootstrap-2-to-3\lib\formatters\css.js:61
                                if (str.indexOf('content-box') > -1) {
                                        ^

TypeError: str.indexOf is not a function
    at constructor._checkPadding (C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme\node_modules\convert-bootstrap-2-to-3\lib\formatters\css.js:61:13)
    at constructor._extractRecursive (C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme\node_modules\convert-bootstrap-2-to-3\lib\formatters\css.js:247:6)
    at constructor.format (C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme\node_modules\convert-bootstrap-2-to-3\lib\formatters\css.js:23:14)
    at CLI.processFileData (C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme\node_modules\convert-bootstrap-2-to-3\lib\cli.js:181:28)
    at CLI.formatFile (C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme\node_modules\convert-bootstrap-2-to-3\lib\cli.js:80:9)
    at CLI.onRead (C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme\node_modules\convert-bootstrap-2-to-3\lib\cli.js:126:9)
    at wrapper (C:\LiferayThemes\workspace\TestThemes\rev-theme\node_modules\convert-bootstrap-2-to-3\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3533:19)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:54:3)
```

The theme is imported via yo from 6.2 project.
It seems gulp is installed correctly as i managed to upgrade empty themes.

What should i change?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Sorry, 
forget it the 'upgrade', it's better to start from scratch with new 7x theme and copy the styles...

Comment: When you know the visual appearance that you're shooting for, creating the same from scratch should be relatively quick - and more productive than looking for any upgrade tool problems. You'll end up with a rough upgrade, but not a pixel-perfect one. And the tuning of an automatically upgrade theme might be harder to get pixel-perfect than a new one, where you remember what you did in every line of CSS today or yesterday.

Comment: Thanks you very @DanieleBaggio for your answer. I am junior in Liferay (also in stack overflow) where i could find a manual for these? I mean creating a theme 7.2 from scratch and styled as the 6.2. Because Liferay's documentation aboout migration with Js toolkit and gulp upgrade

Comment: Thanks you very @OlafKock for your answer. I will really appreciate if you could also check my comment above.

Comment: https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/frameworks/-/knowledge_base/f/themes-introduction and https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/reference/-/knowledge_base/r/theme-generator come to my mind. Typically theme-development starts with a graphical mockup (e.g. an image) that you use to determine colors and margins. You can use the HTML mockup of your old site for that - which CSS to apply exactly is beyond the scope of a generic documentation though.

Comment: Thanks @OlafKock , i have read the documentation, regarding the folder _diffs in my 6.2 project which contains css files , have i create exactly the same files with extension .scss in src/css in 7.2 project?